# Cannot install CodeBlocks 16.01 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: grub2

I am trying to install codeblocks_16.01~ubuntu12.04.1.tar.gz on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS system. I managed to extract it, but on trying to run the command ./configure, i get the following error message at the end....

checking for wx-config... no
configure: error: 
                wxWidgets must be installed on your system.

```
            Please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
            where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
            'wx-config --libs' or 'wx-config --static --libs' command)
            is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent variable and
            wxWindows version is 2.8.0 or above.
```

although when i checked, wxwidgets is already installed on my system, that too version 2.8.0. please help

Comment: Try this `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/path/to/wxwidgets'`, then `./configure` and lets see what happens

Comment: Have you also installed the corresponding wxw-whatever-*dev* packages?

Comment: This question is off topic because it is an abandoned question.